# Get App state from AplicationData.RoamingFolder

Tags: windows, directory, roaming

I am trying to sync roaming settings (using RoamingStorageQuota) on two diffent devices where my app is installed on both but wondering my app state from 1st device to 2nd device not restoring oftenly taking more time to restore/reflect app state. I would like to know approximately how much time RoamingSettings taking to sync state on other device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware there is no guarantee on how long it can take for roaming data to synchronize. In my experience it can take 5-15 minutes, or longer. If you send the high priority roaming setting the synchronization should occur much faster (but still no guarantee), making it more ideal for testing if data is being synchronized or not.

```
// Simple setting
roamingSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello World";
// High Priority setting
roamingSettings.values["HighPriority"] = "65";
```